# New hardware running R code slower than old hardware

Tags: r, performance

To test a new system and get a sense of the performance, I re-ran an [old R project](https://github.com/adatum/Practical_Machine_Learning) which had a timed chunk of code for machine learning.

**New:** [Ryzen 7 2700X](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-2700x) (8 core, 16 threads; base/boost clock = 3.7/4.3 GHz), Fedora 28

**Old:** [Intel i7 4710HQ](https://ark.intel.com/products/78930/Intel-Core-i7-4710HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz) (4 core, 8 threads; base/boost clock = 2.5/3.5 GHz), Windows 7

The results shocked me--the new system is more than 20% *slower* than the old one.

Non-hardware differences:

- Windows 7 vs Fedora 28 (no idea if this should affect performance, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692049/how-to-optimize-r-performance) reported a significant difference). Does R in Windows have more optimized libraries by default?
- The versions of R (Fedora: R-3.5.0-4.fc28 from system repo; Windows: don't remember) and packages used are not the same, but with the 2+ years difference I would think the newer versions and hardware would have a performance advantage.

The difference between running 7 or 15 threads was only ~6%, so the parallelization doesn't scale too well, but I would still expect the newer and higher-clocked hardware to finish (much) faster... and certainly not slower.

Why is this?

---

**EDIT:** I ran a number of scenarios with different numbers of threads and CPB and SMT turned ON and OFF. Note that in some cases the system was being used lightly, so results that are close should be considered within a margin of error.

```
| user    | system | elapsed  | OS        | CPU       | Threads | Turbo/CPB | HT/SMT | Load average |  
|---------|--------|----------|-----------|-----------|---------|-----------|--------|--------------|  
| 126.421 | 0.532  | 2275.998 | Fedora 28 | R7 2700X  | 8       | ON        | OFF    | >42          |
| 126.583 | 0.541  | 2324.118 | Fedora 28 | R7 2700X  | 7       | ON        | OFF    | ?            |
| 136.636 | 0.574  | 2433.931 | Fedora 28 | R7 2700X  | 7       | OFF       | OFF    | ?            |
| 221.49  | 7.48   | 2679.77  | Windows 7 | i7 4710HQ | 7       | ON        | ON     | ?            |
| 155.427 | 0.555  | 3233.690 | Fedora 28 | R7 2700X  | 15      | ON        | ON     | >100         |
| 168.859 | 0.609  | 3247.277 | Fedora 28 | R7 2700X  | 15      | ON        | ON     | ?            |
| 173.312 | 0.650  | 3250.313 | Fedora 28 | R7 2700X  | 16      | ON        | ON     | >70          |
| 161.403 | 0.611  | 3270.098 | Fedora 28 | R7 2700X  | 14      | ON        | ON     | ?            |
| 162.120 | 0.540  | 3442.758 | Fedora 28 | R7 2700X  | 7       | ON        | ON     | ?            |
```

Summary: more threads are better, CPB=ON always seems helpful, but turning SMT=OFF gets the fastest results.

Occasional observation of load averages shows they get very high, far greater than the number of cores. Maybe context switching is killing performance?

Comment: Not sure of the latency or throughput, but I think the old system had DDR3 1600 MHz or similar. The new system uses DDR4 3200 MHz.

Comment: The sustained frequency under load was ~3.9 GHz. SMT/HT is enabled. I tested this system with stress tests like mprime and ycruncher and it was fine. I don't mind running my code again with "turbo" and "HT" disabled (for AMD: core performance boost (CPB) and simultaneous multi-threading (SMT)). But from everything I've read, these are usually helpful not harmful.

Comment: Do you use some optimized math library now? Maybe you have too much parallelism. I would test it sequentially too.

Comment: sorry, but where in your code are you using parallelism? I looked at your code and could not find. you are just registering parallel back-end.

Comment: @F.Privé I am using the default R installation, but I don't know what the libraries might be implementing. Again, since the only data point I have on the old system is when this code is run as-is, what would be the point of testing sequentially?

Comment: @minem Correct, I just register the parallel back-end. Any parallelism is implemented by libraries called for each ML algorithm. Also, I will update later with results from no CPB/SMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for reduced performance with a higher core-count CPU is nested parallelism, due to `caret` and a model (`xgboost` in this case) both parallelizing. This overloads the CPU as indicated by the high load averages, and results in slow execution times.

From `caret`'s [documentation](http://topepo.github.io/caret/parallel-processing.html):

> train, rfe, sbf, bag and avNNet were given an additional argument in their respective control files called allowParallel that defaults to TRUE. When TRUE, the code will be executed in parallel if a parallel backend (e.g. doMC) is registered. When allowParallel = FALSE, the parallel backend is always ignored. The use case is when rfe or sbf calls train. **If a parallel backend with P processors is being used, the combination of these functions will create P^2 processes.**

If there are P^2 processes for P CPU cores, it means each core is overloaded by a factor of P. Therefore it is plausible that higher core-count CPUs may actually perform worse due to more overloading.

The solution is to avoid nested parallelism, by either:

- Using the model's parallelization and not using a parallel backend. This can be done by setting `caret`'s `allowParallel = FALSE`.
- Using a parallel backend and not letting the model parallelize. In the case of `xgboost` this can be done by setting `nthread = 1`. This argument can be set in `caret::train`, or in `caretEnsemble::caretList`, eg.  `tuneList=list(xgbLinear=caretModelSpec(method="xgbLinear", nthread=1))`.

This [interesting blog post](http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2018/1/17/parallel-processing) by `caret`'s author helps show when each method is more advantageous: in the case of a single long running model, the former solution; if there are many resamples, the latter. Because:

> In general, we want to parallelize the longest running part of the
>   algorithm.

---

Using the latter approach, with a 15 worker backend, SMT=ON, CPB=ON, Fedora 28, the overall execution time on the Ryzen 7 2700X improved dramatically by a ~2.8X reduction to:

```
##     user   system  elapsed 
##  109.160    0.638 1168.102
```

The execution time for training just the `xgboost` model, which at 2433 seconds or 40.55 minutes was the majority of the overall execution time, was reduced by ~8 fold to 5 minutes.